# Pathauto URL alias Node taxonomy term translation

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

How can i get pathalias to get the translated taxonomy term for the path alias?

The pattern:

[node:field_glp_product_types]-[node:field_glp_address:city:?]

[node:field_glp_product_types] is a taxonomy reference field.

The following tokens are available, but only the node:field_glp_product_types token gives output, but not translated.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit complicated and is not possible with the normal translation methods.

You will need to use [Entity Translation Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and [Title module](https://www.drupal.org/project/title)

Once you have the above modules configured you should have an option to include translated token for all the entities.